# Replicate background-style:contain on img?

Tags: html, css

Notice that I need to declare the img source from the html (this will be dynamic), so i dont use background here.

**HTML**

```
<div class='some-form'>
  <form>
    <button>...<button>
    <img id="some-img" src="something"/>
    <input id="some-input"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.some-form { 
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
}
.some-form #some-input { 
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); 
  border: 1px solid #2F2F2F; 
  width: 300px; 
  color: #000; 
  opacity: 1; 
}
.some-form #some-img { 
  position:absolute; 
  background-color: #FFF; 
  z-index: -1;
  //background-size: contain; //this does not work
  //background-position: center right 50px; //so this will not work
}
```

How can I get the image to act like contain so that I can align it the way i want?

Comment: You should still be able to declare a background image dynamically within your html, this would probably be an acceptable use case for inline css.

Comment: `img` elements don't function as backgrounds.  Would be easier to change the `img` to a `div` and inline the `background-image` property in the code so you can output it with PHP or whatever.  It might not be perfect from a code quality standpoint but that's by far the easiest solution here.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Is it simply that you want the image to be as wide as the container, but shifted left 50px? If so, what's wrong with setting the right margin to 50px and the width to 100%?

Comment: @ennui i didnt think of that. should i inline all the css for that div?

Comment: No, you just NEED to inline background-image; everything else can be wherever you want to

Comment: @shawn as vals said, no, only inline what you absolutely have to as it is bad practice to use inline css in most cases.  In this case the only thing that needs to be inline is the `background-image` since I imagine you are defining that with server side code that is rendered upon page request (i.e. PHP)

Comment: @ennui your solution worked for me as the most optimal answer. Please write up a solution so i can check mark it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your code as-is, but change `#some-img` from an `img` to a `div` (and specify width and height as needed based on the image dimensions).  It's not possible (at least not in a simple way) to make an `img` element behave as if it was using `background-size` and `background-position` properties since `img` elements are not backgrounds.  So in order to do so, you instead make the image a `div` with a `background-image`.

Since you are dynamically populating the image `src`, you can instead use inline styles to define a `background-image` on the `div`, as this lets you call a PHP or other server-side function to echo the image url (which you can't do in a CSS file).

So for example, keep the CSS you have now (but add height/width or other styles to the `#some-img` `div` as needed) but replace `<img id="some-img" src="something"/>` with something like this:

`<div style="background-image: url(<?php theDynamicImageURL(); ?>);"></div>`

or equivalent in whatever language or method you are using to populate the image dynamically.

There are better ways to do this as inline CSS is generally something that should be avoided, but the use in this case is not too dangerous but it'll work in a pinch and most other methods would either be equally sloppy or a lot more work.

Answer (score 1):

If you include jquery, you can write a script to cheat this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  height = $('#some-img').height();
  width = $('#some-img').width();
  src = $('#some-img').attr('src');
  $('#sime-img').wrap('<div id="contain"></div>');
  $('#contain').height(height).width(width);
  $('#contain').css('background',"url('" + src + "')");
  $('#contain').css('background-sizing','contain');
  $('#some-img').css('opacity','0');
</script>
```

It isn't nice.  You can do the same thing w/o JQuery, I just used it for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to constrain an image to the size of its containing element and center it vertically and horizontally.

This will get you pretty close, but the image will only scale up to its actual size, no bigger.

HTML

```
<div class='some-form'>
  <form>
      <button></button>
        <img id="some-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports"/>
      <input id="some-input" />
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.some-form { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    width:400px;
    height:180px;
    background: rgba(255,255,0,.1); /* for checking that it fits*/
}
.some-form #some-input { 
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    border: 1px solid #2F2F2F; 
    width: 300px; 
    color: #000; 
    opacity: 1; 
}
.some-form #some-img { 
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XNR38/

Good luck!